# How do you control cpu fan speed on fujitsu lifebook T-734

Tags: drivers

I have ubuntu installed on my fujitsu, and it has no pwm capable sensors. Is there any other way to control the cpu fan speed on lifebook t734?

Comment: Hmmm, not use the cpu as much so that it doesn't try to cool itself?